# R: Incompatible Dimensions Error vglm function in VGAM

Tags: r, glm, vgam

**TL;DR**

---

I am running Tobit regressions with the VGAM package in R -- Here is a toy dataset that is consistently giving me an error that I have not been able to diagnose:

```
library(data.table)
library(VGAM)

> sessionInfo()$otherPkgs
$VGAM
Package: VGAM
Version: 0.9-7
Date: 2015-03-06
... <ommitted> ...

reg_data <- structure(list(S = c(1.83271488441825, 0.75411550370994, 0.904938604451928, 
                                 0.75411550370994, 0.75411550370994), H = c(0.6429, 0.7788, 
                                                                            0.6292, 0.8892, 0.2035), W= c(1.52497, 1.1391, 1.59722, 
                                                                                                          1.8406, 1.01865)), .Names = c("S", "H", "W"), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                  "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

minS <- 0.75411550370994
maxS <- 1.83271488441825

m <- vglm(S ~ H, tobit(Upper = maxS, Lower = minS), weights = W, data = reg_data)
Error in lm.wfit(x = cbind(x[!use.i11, ]), y = y[!use.i11, ii], w = w[!use.i11,  : 
  incompatible dimensions
```

---

**Attempts to diagnose**

With traceback:

```
> traceback()
6: stop("incompatible dimensions")
5: lm.wfit(x = cbind(x[!use.i11, ]), y = y[!use.i11, ii], w = w[!use.i11, 
       ii])
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(slot(family, "initialize"))
2: vglm.fitter(x = x, y = y, w = w, offset = offset, Xm2 = Xm2, 
       Ym2 = Ym2, etastart = etastart, mustart = mustart, coefstart = coefstart, 
       family = family, control = control, constraints = constraints, 
       criterion = control$criterion, extra = extra, qr.arg = qr.arg, 
       Terms = mt, function.name = function.name, ...)
1: vglm(y ~ x, tobit(Upper = maxy, Lower = miny), weights = w, data = X)
```

I have viewed the source code for `lm.wfit` and find the source of the error:

```
function (x, y, w, offset = NULL, method = "qr", tol = 1e-07, 
    singular.ok = TRUE, ...) 
{
  <ommitted...>
    if (NROW(y) != n | length(w) != n) 
        stop("incompatible dimensions")
  <ommitted...>
  }
```

I have found the following in the source code for `vglm`:

```
    vglm.fitter <- get(method)
    fit <- vglm.fitter(x = x, y = y, w = w, offset = offset, 
        Xm2 = Xm2, Ym2 = Ym2, etastart = etastart, mustart = mustart, 
        coefstart = coefstart, family = family, control = control, 
        constraints = constraints, criterion = control$criterion, 
        extra = extra, qr.arg = qr.arg, Terms = mt, function.name = function.name, 
        ...)
```

Where the method is defaulted to `vglm.fit`.

I still have not been able to locate where the exclusion criteria `use.i11` is created, what it is doing and why it results in conflicting dimensions between the weights, regressor and regressand.

I have observed that rounding the `minS` and `maxS` to ten or less places results in a successful run, but this is because `maxS` is increased so the 1st observation is no longer right censored and `minS` is increased so the 2nd, 4th and 5th observations are no longer left censored. Both alter the observation's treatment in the maximum likelihood function so I suspect I would be contaminating the regression with false results.

Can someone kindly help diagnose why this type of error occurs?

Comment: did you round the values like this `minS=0.75; maxS=1.83`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I received word from the package's developer that this was indeed a bug and that is has been fixed in the pre-released package [here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~yee/VGAM/prerelease/), which will presumably be upgraded to the CRAN in the next iteration -- or when his book is released.